# quickbooks online sdk to fetch the data from particular company SSL exception

Tags: java, ssl, quickbooks-online

I wanted help regarding quickbooks online sdk. I have downloaded the sdkJavav3SDK2.0.3 and using it to fetch the data from particular company. I have used OAuthAuthorizer, DataService, Customer, QueryResult, etc. for it. But on executing the code I am getting following exception:
"Exception in thread "main" com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.execute(ConnectionInterceptor.java:157)
    at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeRequestInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:76)
    at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:62)
    at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.executeQuery(DataService.java:323)
    at com.quickbooks.QuickBooksTest.main(QuickBooksTest.java:45)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:827)
    at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.ConnectionInterceptor.execute(ConnectionInterceptor.java:150)
    ... 4 more"
Can please someone put some light on it? I have used the approach given in one of the blogs: Created a dummy app first and then a company with data. Using app id i got the keys and secrets from
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground
Then tried connecting it through code.

Regards,
Yogini